# Answers flagged as "Very Low Quality" should have the same tools available to them as when flagged as "Not an Answer"

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, low-quality-posts

Currently, if an answer is marked as "Very Low Quality", we are only given options to delete the post, or ignore the flag.

However, there are many times when the answer should be converted to a comment, but we can't, because the flag was wrong.

If an answer is flagged as "Very Low Quality", then I'd like to see the same tools made available for the post as if it was flagged "Not an Answer" (including [this feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166328/140951), if it is implemented).

This would help the workflow considerably.

It should be noted that this is a technological solution to a *community* problem; we have people who are flagging posts that are not an answer as very low quality (and conversely, posts that are "Not an Answer" as "Very Low Quality", such as link-only answers).

Given that most flags are to be taken as an indication that *something* is wrong, and that we shouldn't nitpick over the type of flag (only if it was helpful or not, [*except* for VLQ, NAA and spam flags for the purposes of the review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160754/140951)), we should have access to all of the tools for an answer no matter *what* the flag is (because we aren't going to change the social conditioning, and rightfully so).

Answer (score 3):

In the [Low quality answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review) queue, I’ve seen a “link-only” answer.

I wish to convert it to a comment, but there is only the option to delete. (I am not a regular reviewer of the Low quality answers queue.)

I skipped the answer, but I am sure that someone else will vote to delete it and potentially a useful link will be lost.

In the past I’ve seen multiple times that useful links were removed and are visible to only 10k+ Users.

Can this change request have a higher priority?