# Converting an answer to a comment from admin/dashboard redirects you to the question page, after the answer has been converted

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, flags

What I did was the following:

- Noticed a flag about an answer pending on admin/dashboard
- Expanded the answer using the arrow shown to the left of the shown posts to read the question
- Clicked on the "mod" link to convert the answer to a comment for the question

Once I did this, I was not anymore on the flag page moderators see; I was in the question page containing the answer I converted to comment.

Comment: I can't repro it following your steps. Can you try again and provide further guidance?

Comment: I have to wait for an answer to be converted in a comment. `:|`

Comment: @Sklivvz This happens to me, as well. Same steps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's fixed and will go out in the next deployment.

Clicking "Submit" in the mod popup now redirects back to the moderator dashboard if that is where you are coming from, instead of the post page.

This behaviour is similar to what happens for review queues.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Ideally, we'd have the "convert to comment" button on *any* flag for an answer.  Can you make that happen?  The flag shouldn't dictate the tools available, the type of the post should.

Comment: @casperOne please open a separate Q for that, we'll see what we can do :-)

Comment: @Sklivvz Talk to Jarrod, he has my wish list.  He knows of this.  Also, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166338/140951 derp.

Answer (score 3):

I just reproduced this following a "Not an Answer" flag on an answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202491/image-processing-code-development

I have screen shots; I followed the same procedure as kiamlaluno.

#### The flag in the flag list:

[image: Flag in Moderator List]

#### Opening the mod menu:

[image: Mod Menu]

#### Converting to comment:

[image: Convert to Comment]

The result after submitting was I ended up on the question page.

To my recollection, this does not happen if we use the "Convert to Comment" button from the mod dashboard; only if we open the preview and use the 'mod' link. I suspect this functionality simply assumes it is being used from the post itself, and therefore redirects back to the question.

Comment: Just confirmed that converting to a comment from the "Convert to Comment" button does *not* direct to the question.