# Allow moderators to convert non-answers to comments on other answers from within the flag queue

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, convert-to-comment, flag-queue

The "convert to comment" tool available from the "mod" link underneath an answer allows moderators to specify the URL or ID of the post that should be the parent of the newly converted comment, as shown here:

[image]

In the flag queue, when there are comments on the flagged answer, the "convert to comment" button [brings up another dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169171/254929) with a choice to convert only the answer or also convert all comments on the answer.

Unlike the normal "mod" link, which uses radio buttons and check boxes to let you configure the action fully before clicking "Submit," the flag queue just shows me a series of push buttons. There's no way for a novice to tell which push button is the last of the series and at what point the action will be performed.

In converting an answer from the flag queue, I had hoped that at some point I'd have the opportunity to specify the target post URL or ID. Instead, once I chose to convert only the answer, the action was performed. To fix this I had to:

1. Undelete the non-answer
2. Convert the non-answer to a comment again, this time from outside of the flag queue so that I could give another answer as the target
3. Delete the comment that the system had created on the question

This is not very user-friendly. Please give us the same "convert to comment" features that are available in the non-queue version of the moderator actions on an answer.

Ideally, this would be done not just by adding any more push buttons or pop-up dialogs but by using UI elements that better distinguish configuring the action from finally performing the action. A pragmatic approach might be to enable the existing pop-up dialog after clicking "convert to comment" in the queue regardless of whether there are comments on the answer, but replace its push buttons with the "Target post URL or ID" input field, "migrate all comments..." check box and a single "Submit" button, as in the non-queue menu. If there are no comments on the answer, the check box can of course be disabled.

Comment: The same thing happened to me two days ago.

Comment: I realise this may not be the right place/way to ask this, but your Question subject is exactly my question - is there a way to use the "Target post URL or ID" so that I can convert an Answer to be a Comment on another Answer, rather than making it a comment on the Question. I tried what I thought might be the url for the Answer in question but was informed i had an incorrect URL

Comment: @petednz-fuzion In any question's URL, the question ID comes after /questions/ (long form URL) or after /q/ (short form URL). If you hover the "share" link under a question, it is the first of the two numeric IDs. You can put this ID in as the target instead of a full URL and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for trying to Answer my question. But not sure if you have quite done so. I am asking how to convert an Answer to be a comment on a different Answer. If I put in the ID eg 277600 how would I make it clear that I want the comment on an Answer rather than on the original question.

Comment: @petednz-fuzion By using the ID of the answer. There is a "share" link under every answer that works the same way as the "share" link under questions, the short form URL will just have an /a/ instead of a /q/ in it. Sorry I was unclear. In the long form URL the answer ID comes at the end as an anchor (preceded by #)

Comment: Thank you - that makes sense - I had looked lots of places for something that might offer the ID but didn't see that. Want to make the above an Answer? And just to complete the answer, the example I am looking at has this in the path a/25743/96 so you mean I just enter 25743 and ignore the /96?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Correct, 96 is your own user ID on that site (https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/u/96/). That's related to tracking for the Announcer-Booster-Publicist series of badges. I will forego writing up an answer since this is not directly related to the feature request on this post.

Comment: right I see. this Q is about Flag Queue behaviour v "normal "mod" link" not about how to get the Answer on to another Answer